# Xpath for an element , all ancestors of which have the same name up to a point

Tags: xpath, recursion

I have an XML that looks like the following:

[xml tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/so0Hq.png)

I need those *tag* elements that have only *son* elements as their ancestors.The only non-*son* ancestor allowed is the root element *parent*.After *parent* no ancestor of *tag* can be anything other than *son* . This xpath therefore would return <tag id="t1" /> and <tag id="t2" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have posted this earlier or may be it does not matter.Here is the nasty looking xpath  I wrote to solve this:

`/parent/(descendant::tag except(descendant::element() except descendant::son)/descendant::tag)`

Hope someone would suggest a better looking alternative.

Answer (score 0):

`//son//tag` would be one solution. Another would be `//tag[ancestor::son]` You could use `/descendent::` in place of `//`; there are differences in the order in which results are reported. There are other variants; which one is best depends on the exact context in which you're doing this.

Comment: your xpath returned all the *tag* elements.The xpath `/parent/descendant::tag[ancestor::son][not(ancestor::daughter)]` works. But here I can filter out only *daughter*. I would like to filter out any element other than *son*